# Cannot connect Optimism-mainnet of Infura with web3.py

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I am trying to connect to Optimism-mainnet using web3 library, but it always shows `False`

Here is my script

```
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://optimism-mainnet.infura.io/v3/{myid}'))

print(w3.isConnected())
```

When I tried for networks other than Optimism they worked.

I tested Optimism-mainnet in Windows and Ubuntu both, but still got same error.

Comment: This page returns 404 not found, why are you expecting it to work?

Comment: It would return that cause I have not exposed my `myid`. It's just for asking question. You get `myid` from the provider.

Comment: have you tried to ping the endpoint with your ID? Is it successful?